# Error using a top toolbar and bottom app bar

Tags: android

I am trying to resolve an error with an error when trying to implement a bottom app bar/navigation view (which is working in other activities) in an activity with a RecyclerView with a top search toolbar. Just wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to implement two toolbars in one activities

Error below:

```
This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request 
Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a 
Toolbar instead.
```

Toolbar_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@mipmap/search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />

 </menu>
```

content_browseadverts.xml

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 



   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Advert.BrowseAdverts"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_browse_adverts">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvBrowseAdverts"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="601dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoAdverts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_records_found"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_browse_adverts.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Advert.BrowseAdverts">

    <include layout="@layout/content_browseadverts" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_filter"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"/>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

BrowseAdverts.java

```
    private DatabaseHelper myDb;

    private AdvertsAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Advert> advertsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout; //why is this saying its not used?
    private TextView noAdvertsView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button btnFilter;

    Toolbar toolbar2;

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private BottomAppBar bottomAppBar;
    private String[] activityTitles;
    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeToolbar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_adverts);

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvBrowseAdverts);
        noAdvertsView = findViewById(R.id.tvNoAdverts);

        final FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CountySheet bottomSheet = new CountySheet();
                bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "countySheet");
            }

        });

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        advertsList.addAll(myDb.getAllAdverts());

        mAdapter = new AdvertsAdapter(this, advertsList, this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
      LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, 
      DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyAdverts();

        bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bar);
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
        imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
        imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        loadNavHeader();

        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, CreateAdvert.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void toggleEmptyAdverts() {

        if (myDb.getAdvertCount() > 0) {
            noAdvertsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noAdvertsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        if (navItemIndex == 0) {
            // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bottom_bar_menu, menu);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


        String userInput = newText.toLowerCase();

        ArrayList<Advert> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Advert advert: advertsList) {
            String name = advert.getAdvertName().toLowerCase();

            if (name.contains(userInput)){
                newList.add(advert);
            }

            mAdapter.setFilter(newList);

        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdvertClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, AdvertDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected_advert" , advertsList.get(position));

        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void loadNavHeader() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 
      Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String firstName = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName", "default");
        String lastName = sharedPreferences.getString("lastname", "default");
        txtName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "default");
        txtWebsite.setText(email);
        String id = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "default");
        int userid = Integer.parseInt(id);
        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(myDb.getImage(userid));
    }

    private void loadHomeFragment() {
        selectNavMenu();

        setToolbarTitle();

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            return;
        }

        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        drawer.closeDrawers();

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }

    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
      NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_adverts:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, BrowseAdverts.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_savedads:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, FavouriteAdverts.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, BrowseUsers.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        Intent intent5 = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MyProfile.class);
                        startActivity(intent5);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_contact:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MainActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_qa:
                        startActivity(new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MainActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("text").commit();
                        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.commit();
                        startActivity(new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, Login.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, 
     bottomAppBar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.app_bar_profile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(BrowseAdverts.this, MyProfile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
        }
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Do you use an `ActionBar` theme or is `windowActionBar` set to `true`? Just read the exception. There's an action bar already supplied. If there is not, please also post your `styles.xml`.

Comment: I used a custom theme as seen above (AppThemeToolbar) , as both top and bottom toolbars were integrated into one with the base theme

Comment: That's the problem. That theme has an action bar by default - set the `windowActionBar` to `false`.